# How to fix 'GitHub.Services.OAuth.VssOAuthTokenRequestException' on a self-hosted runner for GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

```
# Authentication


√ Connected to GitHub

# Runner Registration

Enter the name of runner: [press Enter for sotzimorg] 

This runner will have the following labels: 'self-hosted', 'Linux', 'X64' 
Enter any additional labels (ex. label-1,label-2): [press Enter to skip] 

A runner exists with the same name
Would you like to replace the existing runner? (Y/N) [press Enter for N] y
√ Successfully replaced the runner
Exception of type 'GitHub.Services.OAuth.VssOAuthTokenRequestException' was thrown.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception can occur if the system time of your runner is too far part from the real time.

If this is the cause, then just setting the correct time fixes the problem.